# DataFrame.equals() failing - String conversion to NaN with to_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, cx-oracle

I am writing a CSV file to disk, and then reading in the CSV file to check it matches the in-memory version of the DataFrame.  I am coercing the types of the CSV file, when I read it back in, to match the dtypes of the original dataframe by using the dtypes, and astype.

Thisseems to work fine, but when I do an "equals" on the data frames they are different.  When I then check each individual field, I see these differences:

```
MISMATCH AT INDEX: 21417
Column: REGISTRATION_NUMBER
Source Value:  N/A
Source Type:  <class 'str'>
Target Value:  nan
Target Type:  <class 'float'>
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
MISMATCH AT INDEX: 21709
Column: REGISTRATION_NUMBER
Source Value:  N/A
Source Type:  <class 'str'>
Target Value:  nan
Target Type:  <class 'float'>
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Now I read in the original data from from Oracle using cx_oracle:

```
def get_data(sql):
    # Returns the resulting recordset as a result of executing the SQL, also returns a list of the column names.
    # Results are returned as a tuple (recordset, column names)
    print("Running SQL:\n\n" + sql)

    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('myserver.my_company.net', '1521', service_name='myservice')
    con = cx_Oracle.connect(user='me', password='password', dsn=dsn_tns)

    cur = con.cursor()
    
    cur.execute(sql)
    rs = cur.fetchall()
    
    col_names = []

    # we go through every field
    for field in cur.description:
        col_names.append(field[0])

    return (rs, col_names)


def get_datframe_from_sql_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as sql_file:
        sql = sql_file.read()

    rs, col_names = get_data(sql)

    df = pd.DataFrame(rs, columns=col_names)

    return df;
```

This is my orignal dataframe that I write to disk then read back to compare.

The question is, if this is seen as a string value of N/A in the original data frame, why when I write this to CSV, does it end up as a NaN?

I call this function, and then write the oracle data frame to disk and then read it back in to compare, coercing the data types in the data frame using dtypes.

from data import get_data, get_datframe_from_sql_file
from files import write_data_frames

from datetime import date

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
       
    maa_file = "marketing_applications_all.sql";
    maa_file_types = "marketing_applicastions_types.csv"

    df_maa = get_datframe_from_sql_file(maa_file);
    print(df_maa.head(20));

    maa_file = ();
    todays_date = date.today();
    file_info = ('maa.csv', todays_date, df_maa, maa_file_types);
    files = [file_info];
    write_data_frames(files);








def write_data_frames(data_to_write):
    # the data passed is is a list of tuples
    # each tuple is of the format (file_name, file_date, DataFrame, datatypes_file_name)
    for file_name, file_date , df, datatypes_file_name in data_to_write:
        file_name_final = str(file_date.year).zfill(4) + '_' + str(file_date.month).zfill(2) + '_' + str(file_date.day).zfill(2)  + '__' + file_name;
        df.to_csv(file_name_final, index=True, quotechar='"', doublequote=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, header=True);
        df.dtypes.to_csv(datatypes_file_name, header=False);

        validate_data_frame_vs_file(df, file_name_final,datatypes_file_name);


def validate_data_frame_vs_file(df, file_name, datatypes_file_name):
    print("Validating file " + file_name + " against DataFrame")
    print("Comparing in memory:");

    print(df.dtypes);
    print(str(len(df)) + ' rows');
    df_file = pd.read_csv(file_name, index_col=0, header=0,parse_dates=True)
    df_file_types = pd.read_csv(datatypes_file_name, names=["COLUMN","DATA_TYPE"], header=None);


    # change date columne
    for index, row in df_file_types.iterrows():
        col_name = row["COLUMN"];
        dtype = row["DATA_TYPE"];
        if "DATE" in dtype.upper():
            df_file[col_name] = df_file[col_name].astype(dtype);

    print("Comparing file:");

    print("In Memory....");
    print(df.dtypes);
    print(str(len(df)) + ' rows');

    print("From File....");
    print(df_file.dtypes);
    print(str(len(df_file)) + ' rows');

    print("Are DataFrames equal?")
    frames_equal = df.equals(df_file);

    counter = 0;

    print("Source Data Frame:")
    print(df.head(10));

    df.fillna(value=pd.np.nan, inplace=True);
    df_file.fillna(value=pd.np.nan, inplace=True);

    if frames_equal == False:
        source_columns = df.columns;
        print("Source Columns:")
        print(source_columns);
        for source_index, source_row in df.iterrows():
            counter = counter + 1;

            for source_col in source_columns:
                source_value = source_row[source_col];
                target_value = df_file.loc[source_index, source_col];
                if source_value == source_value: # deals with NaN
                    if source_value != target_value:
                        print("~" * 50);
                        print("MISMATCH AT INDEX:", source_index)
                        print("Column:", source_col);
                        print("Source Value: ", source_value);
                        print("Source Type: ", type(source_value));
                        print("Target Value: ", target_value);
                        print("Target Type: ", type(target_value));
                        print("~" * 50);
```

**Update**:

It is a string "N\A" value in Oracle, and so not sure why writing it out to CSV then renders it as a NaN?

I read in a datframe from Oracle, and write to CSV.  That file has "N/A" values in it.  I read that CSV back in via Pandas, and that field now has a NaN in it for that record.  It is the reading back in of the CSV which causes the issue, the "N/A" value is there in the original write out of the data frame.

[image]

I did a quick test CSV file, and N/A is not an issue?"

[image]

Here it is in the CSV.

[image]

Read in as a Nan, in an object type column?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tiny mismatch between df.read_csv and df.to_csv that might be the reason for the behaviour.

If you write to a csv, the default will be `''`. To quote the [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

> **na_repstr**, *default `''`*
> Missing data representation.

However, if you read from a csv the NA values are defined as:

> **na_values** *scalar, str, list-like, or dict, optional*    Additional strings to recognize as NA/NaN. If dict passed, specific per-column NA values. By default the following values are interpreted as NaN: **`''`**, ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’, ‘-nan’, ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘’, ‘N/A’, ‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘n/a’, ‘nan’, ‘null’.

So, read_csv() does accept a lot more NA values and converts them to `NaN`.

You can define the accepted NA values with these two parameters to solve your mismatch.

```
df.to_csv(file_name_final, index=True, quotechar='"', doublequote=True,
          quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, header=True, na_repstr='NA');
```

```
df_file = pd.read_csv(file_name, index_col=0, header=0,parse_dates=True,  
                      na_values='NA', keep_default_na=False)
```

Beware, this may break other values in your dataframe.

Comment: Thanks.  Why then with my test file did N/A not come in as a NaN?  See example at bottom of original post

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out:

```
df = pd.read_csv("2020_07_24__maa.csv", header=0, keep_default_na = False)
```

Pandas interprets N/A as a NaN value (!)